# How to change the title of the moderating variable in an effects plot?

Tags: r, plot, graph, interaction

I am using base plot and the "effects" package together to plot an interaction. While I can change the xlab and the ylab, I was wondering how I can change the title of the facet wrap (which defaults to the code I use for it in my R script). Moreover, I would like to avoid the suboptinal option of going back and renaming the variable earlier on in the analysis.

Here is the plot. You can see that the moderating variable is the code I assigned it in R. I would like to rename it.

[image: Here is the plot. You can see that the moderating variable is the code I assigned it in R. I would like to rename it.]

```
plot(
  effect("incaccomp_pc09.recode * Congress.recode", 
         Logit.LegA.Interact
  ), 
  xlab = "Congressional Approval",
  ylab = "Probability of Voting for a INC",
  main = "Interaction Plot of Accomplish  * Cong Approval"
)
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are you trying to modify, facet labels or the plot title?

Comment: Please post some data. That makes it easier for people who want to try to help you. Read [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes! I'm trying to modify the facet labels!